# When attempting to loaddata - get error problem installing fixture

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to load data from a db.json file I created (Sqlite db was the source).  The original database is Sqlite, and I am try to migrate to Mysql.

Everything works fine under Sqlite.  I get the following error:

django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture '/home/balh/blah/db.json': Could not load trackx_site.Segment(pk=1): (1054, "Unknown column 'program_id' in 'field list'")

It seems like the Mysql tables do not have the foreign key or something?....  The models look like this:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    air_date             = models.DateField(default="0000/00/00")
    air_time             = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    service              = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    block_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
    block_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    running_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    running_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    remaining_time       = 
models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    title                = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    locked_flag          = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    locked_expiration    = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    deleted_flag         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    library              = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=190,blank=True)
    mc                   = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    producer             = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    editor               = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    remarks              = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    audit_time           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    audit_user           = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)

class Segment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
      ordering = ['sequence_number']

    program = models.ForeignKey(Program,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='segments',   # link to Program
    )
    sequence_number          = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6,default="0.00")
    title                    = models.CharField(max_length=190, blank=True)
    bridge_flag              = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seg_length_time          = models.TimeField()
    seg_length_time_delta    = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    seg_run_time             = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    seg_run_time_delta       = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    seg_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
    seg_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
    author                   = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    voice                    = models.CharField(max_length=64,null=True,default=None,blank=True)
    library                  = models.CharField(max_length=190)
    summary                  = models.TextField()
    audit_time               = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    audit_user               = models.CharField(null=True,max_length=32)
```

I also get a error when I attempt to run the server with the Mysql db settings. It will not allow me to add a record into the model and gives me an error complaining about program_id.  I dont have anything named program_id that I am aware of.. (I looks through all the code).
It works fine when I run with Sqlite db settings. Adds programs and segments just fine.

Don't know what's wrong here. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my mysql database was not migrating correctly. Part of the problem was it was trying to do all the migrations, but since it was the inital build of the new database I did not need to have all the migrations (and somehow something  was happening correctly in there).  Removed all of the migrations, did initial makemigrations and migrate, and my Foreign Key was created correctly, no more problems.